# Exclude scroll animation function from some ID's

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, animation, scroll

I did add JavaScript code for animating scrolling with menu to each block with an ID. Then I added Bootstrap's tabs which got messed up because of my animation scrolling.

I wonder how I can make my scroll animation stop working on bootstrap tabs?

**Scroll animation code**

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 800);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

**Bootstrap tabs**

```
<div role="tabpanel">

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and fixed it like this. In the beginning of the code:

```
$(function() {
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {`
```

you have to add a class to the "a" alement. Let's say you add the class `scrollnav`.

It will be like this:

```
$(function() {
$('a.scrollnav[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {`
```

So this code (smooth scroll) will work only on the `a` elements with this class.

Your Java should look like:

```
$(function() {
    $('a.scrollnav[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
              var target = $(this.hash);
              target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
              if (target.length) {
                 $('html,body').animate({
                     scrollTop: target.offset().top
                 }, 800);
                 return false;
              }
          }
     });
});
```

And every `a` element in your menu (or other nav link) must have the class `scrollnav`.